# angular2-google-maps click-event for marker

Tags: typescript, angular

Is someone familiar with this library?: https://angular-maps.com/
If so can someone help me creating a click event on the marker i tried this:

```
 <sebm-google-map-marker *ngFor="#location of locations" (click)="updateDiv()"
[latitude]="location.lat" [longitude]="location.lng" [label]="location.id">

updateDiv() {
console.log('check');
}
```

But it seems not to work? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think that you could try the following (`markerClick` event instead of the `click` one):

```
<sebm-google-map-marker *ngFor="#location of locations"   
  (markerClick)="updateDiv()" [latitude]="location.lat"
  [longitude]="location.lng" [label]="location.id">

updateDiv() {
  console.log('check');
}
```

See this doc in the Outputs section:

- https://angular-maps.com/docs/api/latest/ts/core/SebmGoogleMapMarker-directive.html

Comment: How to get the corresponding latitude and longitude for the marker clicked? Please help me.

Answer (score 4):

You need to use `markerClick` instead of `click` like this:

```
(markerClick)="updateDiv()"
```

See also documentation https://angular-maps.com/docs/api/latest/ts/core/SebmGoogleMapMarker-directive.html#Outputs