# Angular 2+ Google Maps get coordinates from click position on map to update marker position

Tags: angular, google-maps, coordinates, google-maps-markers

I want to do something which is probably really simple however I can't seem to figure it out.

I integrated the Angular2+ Google Maps module to my Angular project (https://angular-maps.com/). Now I want to be able to replace the marker by clicking somewhere on the map. In order to do this I need to fetch the coordinates of the location where the user clicked on the map. If I have these coordinates I can update the longitude and latitude to move the marker. However I am not sure how to fetch the clicked location.

This is my map implementation in the html document:

```
<agm-map [latitude]="latitude" [longitude]="longitude" [zoom]="zoom" [streetViewControl]="false" [mapTypeControl]="true" [fullscreenControl]="true" (mapClick)="placeMarker()">
   <agm-marker [latitude]="latitude" [longitude]="longitude" [iconUrl]="'assets/geomarker.png'"></agm-marker>
   <agm-circle [latitude]="latitude" [longitude]="longitude" [radius]="20" [fillOpacity]="0.50" [fillColor]="'#00A19A'"></agm-circle>
</agm-map>
```

I am using the mapClick output event. (https://angular-maps.com/api-docs/agm-core/components/AgmMap.html) However this event does not seem to emit any coordinates. I am cathing the event like this right now:

```
placeMarker(){
  console.log(event);
}
```

And this is the output:

```
MouseEvent {isTrusted: true, screenX: 3657, screenY: 67, clientX: 401, clientY: 318…}
altKey
:
false
bubbles
:
true
button
:
0
buttons
:
0
cancelBubble
:
false
cancelable
:
true
clientX
:
401
clientY
:
318
composed
:
true
ctrlKey
:
false
currentTarget
:
null
defaultPrevented
:
false
detail
:
1
eventPhase
:
0
fromElement
:
null
isTrusted
:
true
layerX
:
364
layerY
:
154
metaKey
:
false
movementX
:
0
movementY
:
0
offsetX
:
364
offsetY
:
154
pageX
:
401
pageY
:
318
path
:
Array(23)
relatedTarget
:
null
returnValue
:
true
screenX
:
3657
screenY
:
67
shiftKey
:
false
sourceCapabilities
:
InputDeviceCapabilities
srcElement
:
div
target
:
div
timeStamp
:
18285.225000000002
toElement
:
div
type
:
"click"
view
:
Window
which
:
1
x
:
401
y
:
318
__proto__
:
MouseEvent
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I have found the answer myself.

On the HTML side I had to use:

```
(mapClick)="placeMarker($event)"
```

And on the typescript side I had to use:

```
  placeMarker($event){
    console.log($event.coords.lat);
    console.log($event.coords.lng);
  }
```

This returns the latitude and lontitude individually, now I can push these coordinates to the marker in the HTML file to update its location.

Comment: @Anytoe , It is only updating for map click other than displayed marker. When i am clicking marker, i am unable to get its lat and lng. Can you please show me this?

Comment: I would say that's a different event? Have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37463214/angular2-google-maps-click-event-for-marker. Does that help?

Comment: Same applies to a right click event: `(mapRightClick)="mapRightClickMap($event)`. Just don't forget the $event parameter and don't give it a type such as `EventEmitter`, leave it as `any`

Comment: event.coords is undefined.?

Comment: Something is broken in agm 3.3.0 beta...the event argument is NOT of type google.maps.MouseEvent that allows the coordinates to be read. Can someone please help if they figured it out? Thank you.