# clickMap event doesn't return coordinates | Ionic | Angular Google Maps

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4, angular-google-maps, agm

I have a map and a mapClick event and I'm trying to get coordinates.

**ts file**

```
onMapClick(event) {
        console.log(event);
    }
```

**html file**

```
<agm-map (mapClick)="onMapClick($event)" [latitude]="latitude" [longitude]="latitude"
                         [zoom]="13">
    <agm-marker [latitude]="latitude" [longitude]="latitude"></agm-marker>
</agm-map>
```

But the console returns c instead of coordinates. I have the same code in another project (Angular) and it works as expected.

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44887015/angular-2-google-maps-get-coordinates-from-click-position-on-map-to-update-mark

Comment: I have already tried that and it prints "core.js:6228 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'lat' of undefined". It doesn't apply on Ionic for whatever reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked the `@agm/core` version and it was the `3.0.0-beta.0` so I tried to go back to the previous version `1.1.0` and now it works as expected.