Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'lat')
Hello i m trying to implement google maps in my Angular project , the map is showing fine but i added a function to get the latitude and longitude when the user click on the map but i keep getting the cannot read error
App component :
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'PI';
  latitude = 51.678418;
  longitude = 7.809007;
  locationChosen = false;

  onChoseLocation(event) {
    this.latitude = event.coords.lat;
    this.longitude = event.coords.lng;
    this.locationChosen = true;}
}

HTML :
<agm-map [latitude]="latitude" [longitude]="longitude" (mapClick)="onChoseLocation($event)">
  <agm-marker [latitude]="latitude" [longitude]="longitude" *ngIf="locationChosen"></agm-marker>
</agm-map>


Did u try the 'mapClick' output ?
I see that in the doc 'https://angular-maps.com/api-docs/agm-core/components/agmmap#source'

yes i did same problem it was mapClick i changed it and forgot to change it back :(

this is not a Z-index problem or pointer-event : none effect ?

i dont know but nothing is working the coords.alt and coords.lan is not working

What do u have in 'event' when u console log the property

i get : Map Click c

try : onChoseLocation(event :  any) { console.log(event) }

i only get the letter : C

is there something i should reinstall  ?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64669621/clickmap-event-doesnt-return-coordinates-ionic-angular-google-maps
